# Font Size defined in VW Units appearing way too big in dekstop

Tags: css, font-size, font-family, font-awesome-5

I originally had all the font sizes defined in px units
Then i read about responsive font sizes everywhere and i was inclined to use VW units for font sizes

So i just converted all the px values to vw using a converter and changed every px font value to vw unit in my CSS ( the values of vw ranged from 3,4 to 6,7 )

i was using a mobile phone while doing so and the new VW units for fonts looked as good as px units on my device  ( all good till here )

Today i tried my website in dekstop and it looked horrible , the font was so big that the **whole screen was filled with just 3 lines of text** ;-;

Now i know ,i can use media Query to define a lower value of VW units for dekstop ( large width )

But then I don't understand what's the point/benefit of using hyped vw units for font size  , i can just use media Query for px font size too and call it responsive

If someone has a better approach to my reported problem , please suggest something

Comment: Heydon Pickering and Andy Bell are using a combination of `vw` and `rem`; the first because of responsiveness and the second one to respect user's font size setting in their browsers. So they came up with this rough interpolation: `calc(0.33vw + 1rem)`. Adjust it to taste. Read more here: https://every-layout.dev/rudiments/units/

Answer (score 3):

CSS `vw` is 1 percent of the width of the window. [CSS units reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

So if you set something to `10vw` on a mobile device with a width 300px it will be 30px. (`300px/10 = 30px`). However, on desktop say 1000px wide `10vw` will be 100px. You see why it changes drastically.

Basically, you probably shouldn't use `vh/vw` for font sizes. You should use other percentage-based units like `em`, `rem` or `%`. Reserve viewport-width & viewport-height for large scale layout needs like column sizes or footers.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Although as far as i know. em , rem and % are just relative font sizes dependent on other class. So technically they are not responsive. So at the end the only way to make my text responsive is use the media Query ? ( I usually don't prefer it because adding font sizes media query after every 200px  width will just bloat the css too much unnecessarily ?

Comment: You need to read up on CSS units. `em` and `%` are based on their direct parent. `rem` is based on the **root** `font-size`. For example if you set something to be 33% of a div (`display:block`) by default that's the width of the window then 33% will constantly change based on the window size.